# Wlan0 ip address location

Tags: 14.04

I have created Ubuntu system as wifi access point. By default it takes 10.42.0.1 as it's ip. From which file this information is taken by ubutu? I mean where it is stored that wlan0 corresponds to 10.42.0.1.  I know that a file is created in /etc/network...(don't remember the path exactly) but it does not have any info regarding 10.42.0.1.i want to know where it is assigned from n the file location.guys pls help

Comment: Thanks for the reply.i wil go through the manual.but can I change 10.42.0.1 to 192.168.x.x. coz when I am creating access point in Ubuntu,and changing it's corresponding file to have static IP, the server in Ubuntu is not accepting any data from client through WiFi, reason I guess "instead of shared to other computers option, I kept as static IP". How can I assign different ip to Ubuntu wlan0 and stil have data shared?

Answer (score 0):

It's the default built into the software.

From the [NetworkManager Reference Manual](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nm-settings-ifcfg-rh.html):

> NetworkManager supports traditional values *none* (static), *dhcp*. But it
>   also allows additional values to enable new addressing methods. They
>   are *autoip* for IPv4 link-local addressing using Avahi daemon and
>   *shared* for connection sharing. When *shared* is used, NetworkManager
>   assigns the interface 10.42.0.1, or it uses the first static address,
>   if configured.

Obviously it is because 42 is the answer to [life, the universe, and everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy).